# os.system отслеживание завершения

Tags: python

Из своего приложения вызываю еще одну программу. Допустим, так

```
import os
os.system('gedit 1.py')
```

Возможно ли отследить, когда запущенная программа была закрыта? И приступить к выполнению следующей.

Comment: [subprocess — Subprocess management](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

Тем более `os.system` - устаревший вызов.

Comment: как вариант посмотреть если в процессах 1.py, использовав proc например

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы. Буду гуглить.

Comment: Если os.system() в Питоне это вызов **system()** из *libc*, то отслеживать не надо, это синхронная функция, она внутри **wait()** вызывает.

Другой вопрос, если запускаемая Вами через нее команда сама что-то запустит в фоне и завершится.

Comment: @avp, именно, это обертка для `system()`, объявленная устаревшей (не следует использовать в новом коде на Python:

> 17.1.4.3. Replacing os.system()
sts = os.system("mycmd" + " myarg")
# becomes
sts = call("mycmd" + " myarg", shell=True)

Answer (score 1):

Дам ответ для текущей версии python 3.+

На данный момент подобная задача решается через модуль `subprocess`. Создание вызова программы через объект `Popen` происходит синхронно. То есть, после того, как вы создадите вызов сторонней программы, она запуститься и выполнение вашего скрипта перейдет в режим получения данных, пока вызванная программа не будет завершена. После этого объект `Popen` предоставит доступ к перехваченным от программы данным (это данных стандартных каналов вывода, ввода и ошибок). С этого момента можно вызывать следующую программу.

Вот пример подобной реализации вызова двух команд `ping` для разных популярных поисковиков.

```py
import subprocess

# вызываем первую команду ping
    # начало выполнения команды
pop1 = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "google.com"], encoding='cp866', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    # окончание выполнения команды
out1 = pop1.stdout.read()
print(" google.com ".center(80, '='))
print(out1)

# вызываем вторую команду ping
    # начало выполнения команды
pop2 = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "ya.ru"], encoding='cp866', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    # окончание выполнения команды
out2 = pop2.stdout.read()
print(" ya.ru ".center(80, '='))
print(out2)
```

Обратите внимание, что между выводом `out1` и `out2` есть промежуток времени - это и есть время выполнения второй команды `ping`.